# Loading objects based on worksheets in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where one or more of the worksheets represents a `customer`.  I've also built a `customer` class, and a method that loads applicable worksheet data into each customer object.  The method works like so

```
LoadCustomers()
  For each worksheet in the workbook
    If the worksheet contains a named range, "CustomerKey"
      Create a new customer object
      Set its key equal to the value in the range "CustomerKey"
      Load data from the worksheet into the object
    End If
  Loop
End
```

This all works great... until someone decides to make a copy of a customer worksheet inside the same workbook.  Then the next time the workbook gets opened and the `LoadCustomers()` method runs, it finds a duplicate customer key and it crashes and burns.

What's a good workaround for this without preventing people from copying sheets within the workbook?  The less complexity the better.

Comment: Proper Error Handling?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your customer objects, keep a reference to all customer objects in a `Dictionary` - with the CustomerKey as the key. When you create a new customer object, first test if the new CustomerKey already exists in the dictionary - in this case, skip the creation of a new object but rather show a message to the user.

The use the Dictionary, you need to add a reference to `MS Scripting Runtime`. Then your pseudo-code would like this:

```
Global gDicCustomers as Dictionary

LoadCustomers()
  Set gDicCustomers = New Dictionary
  For each worksheet in the workbook
    If the worksheet contains a named range, "CustomerKey"
      If gDicCustomers.Exists(CustomerKey) Then
        MsgBox "Dont screw with the customer worksheets - or at least be so decent to change the customer key, too!"
      Else
         Create a new customer object
         Set its key equal to the value in the range "CustomerKey"
         Load data from the worksheet into the object
         gDicCustomers.Add CustomerKey, CustomerObject
       End If
    End If
  Loop
End
```

The other advantage of this approach is that you can always reference any customer object with `gDicCustomers(CustomerKey)`...